# Git Remote Updates finder in Java

Tags: jgit, git-remote

I have a requirement to find if there are any updates in Git Remote branch compared to the local branch cloned earlier. If there are any updates available, application must notify the user and on user consent, a pull request has to be performed in Java.

I tried using JGIT
`org.eclipse.jgit.lib.BranchTrackingStatus.of(git.getRepository(), git.branchList().call().get(0).getName()).getBehindCount()` to know if my local repository is behind the remote repository. **This is always returning 0**.

1st parameter to the function **BranchTrackingStatus.of** must be a Repository object, and the object passed is local repository object.

Appreciate any suggestions to tackle this scenario.

Comment: Do you want to do this with *jgit*, or with *git?*

Comment: I want to try this with jgit using Java Code, not with Git commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BranchTrackingStatus` compares a local branch with the configured remote tracking branch, e.g. `refs/heads/foo` with `refs/remotes/origin/foo` (if the default naming convention is followed).

The method does not update the remote tracking branch. Unless you first fetch the branch in question from the remote repository, no change will be reported.

```java
FetchResult result = git.fetch()
    .setRemote("origin")
    .setRefSpecs("refs/heads/foo:refs/remotes/origin/foo")
    .call().
```

The `result` holds details of the succeeded operation or why it couldn't be completed.

Does that solve your problem?

Comment: I made these changes and verified that the FetchResult object holds the details of modifications performed. Same code when ran 2nd time has no data, which means earlier fetch has already fetched the changes to local and 2nd fetch also brought in same changes. Comparing these 2 branches have no delta and hence this doesn't solve my problem completely. I need a fallback mechanism to clear the local contents if user doesn't wish to fetch upon seeing the available updates. git.clean().call() API didn't work here. Kindly suggest any other API which I could try out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you want to achieve. I'd suggest to describe the problem in detail and what you've tried so far (preferrrably a standalone test case) in a separate question.

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69265916/perform-git-pull-using-java-jgit-with-user-consent-yes-no for more information on the problem statement