# Perform Git PULL using Java [JGIT] with user consent (Yes/No)

Tags: jgit

**Requirement**

Suppose we have already performed git clone to local repository. Now there exist some updates to remote repository file. On the application start up, I would like to find if there are any updates in remote repository compared to local repository. If updates available, a notification must be shown to user of application and ask for his/her consent to download those updates. If user gives consent to download the updates, application has to pull those changes else skip downloading for this run/launch. When user launches application for next time, again the same check has to be performed.

**Problem Statement**

As suggested in [Git Remote Updates finder in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69250170/git-remote-updates-finder-in-java) fetched the remote branch and found the updates. This worked fine for first time. When the same steps were repeated, **FetchResult** didn't have the updates of Remote Repository.

**Already Tried**

Tried `git.reset().setMode(ResetType.HARD).call()` and `git.revert().call()` when user clicks NO to download the updates so that next start of the application gets the same delta when it performs Git FETCH

**PSEUDO Code**

```
if(alreadyCloned){
 check if updates available in remote - as per the [suggestions in above link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69250170/git-remote-updates-finder-in-java)
 if(updatesAvailable){
    fetch user consent to download
    if(user permits to download updates) {
       perform git pull
    } else {
       clear local repository
    }
 } else {
      do nothing
 }
}
```

Comment: This post is in continuation with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69250170/git-remote-updates-finder-in-java

Comment: As before, if you want to  do this in jgit and not plain Git, don't use the [tag:git] tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is a mismatch of your understanding and how Git works w.r.t. remote updates.

For each local branch (e.g. `refs/heads/foo`) usually there is a 'tracking branch' (e.g. `refs/remotes/origin/foo`). The fetch command updates the tracking branch. Hence, if the remote repo didn't change, subsequent fetches won't change the local repo.

To find out if a branch has changed, you should first fetch the branch (which updates the tracking branch if there are changes) and then compare the local branch with its corresponding remote tracking branch (e.g. using the `BranchTrackingStatus`).

Finally, if the commits of the remote should be *applied* ('user permits to download updates' in your program flow), then reset, rebase, or merge the local branch to/with the tracking branch.

Note, that pulling a branch in Git is a composite operation that first fetches commits from the remote repo (which updates the remote tracking branch) and then rebases or merges the local branch with the tracking branch.

Comment: I was not aware of 'tracking branch' in Git. This solution worked for me to find out if local branch is behind remote branch.